# How to get Scalar-value-function result VB.net form through stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net

VB.Net Code

```vb
' Getting Records Before Transfer to GL
Call OpenAccConnection(lblUserName.Text, lblPassword.Text)
Dim odcTotalsForTransferGL As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("spPet_TotalsForTransferGL", conAccounts)
odcTotalsForTransferGL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
' Parameter Assigning
Dim strCompanyCode As OleDbParameter = odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@ComCod", OleDbType.VarChar, 2)
strCompanyCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Dim strLocationCode As OleDbParameter = odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@LocCod", OleDbType.VarChar, 2)
strLocationCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Dim strPettyCashDate As OleDbParameter = odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@PetDat", OleDbType.VarChar, 8)
strPettyCashDate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Dim strBegVNo As OleDbParameter = odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@BegVNo", OleDbType.Integer)
strBegVNo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
Dim strEndVNo As OleDbParameter = odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@EndVNo", OleDbType.Integer)
strEndVNo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
Dim strVouTotal As OleDbParameter = odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@VouTotal", OleDbType.Integer)
strVouTotal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
Dim decPetTotal As OleDbParameter = odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@PetTotal", OleDbType.Decimal)
decPetTotal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
Dim intFinancialDates As OleDbParameter = odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@FinancialDates", OleDbType.Integer)
intFinancialDates.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
' Passing Parameters
' Company Code
strCompanyCode.Value = cboCompanyCode.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(0, 2)
' Location Code
strLocationCode.Value = cboLocationCode.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(0, 2)
' Petty Cash Date(Year & Month)
strPettyCashDate.Value = dtPettyCashDate.Value.Year.ToString + dtPettyCashDate.Value.Month.ToString("D2") + "01"
' Accounts Database Open
conAccounts.Open()
' Stored Procedure Process
Dim odrTotalsForTransferGL As OleDbDataReader = odcTotalsForTransferGL.ExecuteReader()
If odrTotalsForTransferGL.HasRows Then
    Do While odrTotalsForTransferGL.Read
        lblAccPeriod.Text = odrTotalsForTransferGL.GetValue(4).ToString.Substring(0, 4) + "/" + odrTotalsForTransferGL.GetValue(4).ToString.Substring(5, 4)
        lblFiscalMonth.Text = odrTotalsForTransferGL.GetValue(4).ToString.Substring(9, 2)
        lblBegVNo.Text = odrTotalsForTransferGL.GetValue(0).ToString
        lblEndVNo.Text = odrTotalsForTransferGL.GetValue(1).ToString
        lblPettyTotal.Text = odrTotalsForTransferGL.GetValue(3).ToString
    Loop
End If
```

Stored Procedure

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPet_TotalsForTransferGL] 

    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ComCod as varchar(2),
    @LocCod as varchar(2),
    @PetDat as varchar(8),  
    @BegVNo as int OUT,
    @EndVNo as int OUT,
    @VouTotal as int OUT,
    @PetTotal as decimal(12,2) OUT,
    @FinancialDates as varchar(10) OUT

    AS
    BEGIN

    SELECT MIN(PettyDetail.DPetVouNo),
           MAX(PettyDetail.DPetVouNo),
           MAX(PettyDetail.DPetVouNo) - MIN(PettyDetail.DPetVouNo),
           ISNULL(SUM(PettyDetail.DPetAmount), 0)
           FROM PettyDetail
                WHERE (PettyDetail.DPetComCode = @ComCod) AND
                      (PettyDetail.DPetLocCode = @LocCod) AND
                      (YEAR(PettyDetail.DPetDate) = YEAR(CONVERT(Date,@PetDat,111))) AND
                      (MONTH(PettyDetail.DPetDate) = MONTH(CONVERT(Date,@PetDat,111)))

    /* Getting Financial Dates */

    EXECUTE @FinancialDates = dbo.fnApp_GetFinancialDates @PetDat

END
```

Scalar Function

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnApp_GetFinancialDates] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @PetDat as varchar(8)
)
--RETURNS int(10)
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here
    --DECLARE @FinancialDates int(10)
    DECLARE @FinancialDates varchar(10)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    IF MONTH(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111)) BETWEEN 4 AND 12
        BEGIN
            SELECT @FinancialDates = (SELECT
                                             CAST((YEAR(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111))) as varchar) +
                                             CAST((YEAR(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111)) + 1) as varchar) +
                                             REPLICATE('0',(2-(LEN(CAST((MONTH(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111)) - 3) as varchar))))) + (CAST((MONTH(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111)) - 3) as varchar)))
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @FinancialDates = (SELECT
                                             CAST((YEAR(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111)) - 1)as varchar) +
                                             CAST((YEAR(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111))) as varchar) +
                                             CAST((MONTH(CONVERT(date,@PetDat,111)) + 9) as varchar))
        END
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @FinancialDates

END
```

Above function @FinancialDates value didn't return to the .Net form. But other results are return to form.

Can any one please help me to solve this problem. Procedure & Function run correctly in Query Manager.

[image]

Comment: Please look at the preview of your question before submitting in future and don't submit if the formatting is a mess.  Also, when you add an image and it says "enter image description here", the idea is that you enter the image description there.

Comment: As for the issue, your sproc executes the function and assigns the value to an output parameter but nowhere in your VB code do you get the value of that parameter after executing the sproc.

Comment: jmcilhinney - @FinancialDates variable value didnt come to VB code.

Comment: One thing that I have found whenever I've used output parameters is that, while it seems like it should, setting the `Direction` of a parameter to `Output` doesn't seem to work.  I've always found that I've had to set the `Direction` to `InputOutput` in ADO.NET even if the parameter is output only in SQL.  Even if you make that change though, as I said before, you haven't written any code to get the value of that parameter so why would you expect to have the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options :

- Option 1 : change EXECUTE @FinancialDates = dbo.fnApp_GetFinancialDates @PetDat, 
  to :

  > SET @FinancialDates = dbo.fnApp_GetFinancialDates(@PetDat)
- Option 2 : Include your fnApp_GetFinancialDates function  in your SELECT statement (and you could just remove the  @FinancialDates as varchar(10) OUT parameter statement.

  ```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPet_TotalsForTransferGL] 
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @ComCod as varchar(2),
  @LocCod as varchar(2),
  @PetDat as varchar(8)

  AS
  BEGIN

  SELECT MIN(PettyDetail.DPetVouNo) AS 'BegVNo',
     MAX(PettyDetail.DPetVouNo) AS 'EndVNo',
     MAX(PettyDetail.DPetVouNo) - MIN(PettyDetail.DPetVouNo) AS 'VouTotal',
     ISNULL(SUM(PettyDetail.DPetAmount), 0) AS 'PetTotal'
     dbo.fnApp_GetFinancialDates (@PetDat) AS 'FinancialDates'
     FROM PettyDetail
          WHERE (PettyDetail.DPetComCode = @ComCod) AND
                (PettyDetail.DPetLocCode = @LocCod) AND
                (YEAR(PettyDetail.DPetDate) = YEAR(CONVERT(Date,@PetDat,111))) AND
                (MONTH(PettyDetail.DPetDate) = MONTH(CONVERT(Date,@PetDat,111)))
  END
  ```

and for the option 2 VB code :

```
  If odrTotalsForTransferGL.HasRows Then
  Do While odrTotalsForTransferGL.Read
    lblAccPeriod.Text = odrTotalsForTransferGL("FinancialDates").ToString.Substring(0, 4) + "/" + odrTotalsForTransferGL("FinancialDates").ToString.Substring(5, 4)
    lblFiscalMonth.Text = odrTotalsForTransferGL("FinancialDates").ToString.Substring(9, 2)
    lblBegVNo.Text = odrTotalsForTransferGL("BegVNo").ToString
    lblEndVNo.Text = odrTotalsForTransferGL("EndVNo").ToString
    lblPettyTotal.Text = odrTotalsForTransferGL("PetTotal").ToString
  Loop
End If
```

edited : and don't forget to remove the following code because they are not necessary and will produce errors since the stored proc has no output parameters anymore:

```
Dim strBegVNo As OleDbParameter = 
odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@BegVNo", OleDbType.Integer)
strBegVNo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
Dim strEndVNo As OleDbParameter = 
odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@EndVNo", OleDbType.Integer)
strEndVNo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
Dim strVouTotal As OleDbParameter = 
odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@VouTotal", OleDbType.Integer)
strVouTotal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
Dim decPetTotal As OleDbParameter = 
odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@PetTotal", OleDbType.Decimal)
decPetTotal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
Dim intFinancialDates As OleDbParameter = 
odcTotalsForTransferGL.Parameters.Add("@FinancialDates", OleDbType.Integer)
intFinancialDates.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```

Comment: Thank you Noldy Nayoan. Option 2 is working. Thank you again.

Comment: I've added some vb code for option 2. It's better if you use named parameters, you don't have to worry about the order of the returned colums data (i.e GetValue(index)).. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I edited my VB code too. Thank you again